# rails generate scaffold error - using wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am on OSX Lion.
I updated my xCode.
I installed git.
I installed curl.
I installed rvm.
I installed ruby 1.9.3 and rails using rvm.

I created a new app.
When I run rails generate I get the following error:

```
$ rails generate
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:86:in `load_specification': private method `specification_version=' called for #<Gem::Specification:0x33a22c> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:401:in `initialize'
    from (eval):3:in `load_specification'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:121:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:86:in `load_specification'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:121:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:120:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:75:in `from_gems_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:47:in `from_installed_gems'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:109:in `source_index'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:187:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:66:in `active_gem_with_options'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:59:in `require_gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:17
```

It seems like it should not be looking at that directory as it is ruby 1.8. (Maybe this is the default version installed with OSX?)

Any help to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified the ruby you use ? `ruby -v` && `gem -v`

Answer (score 0):

First step is to start a new shell session. Then check which version of ruby is actually used `ruby -v`, and the one rvm says is in use. If the two are different, you probably forgot to, or badly configured your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`.

I always had errors like this with rvm. I know a lot of people are happy with rvm, but if it keeps bugging you, I suggest moving to [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build)/[rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). Never had one probleme since I switch a few months ago, and less black magic in my sense.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you havent told RVM to use ruby 1.9.3..

If your using RVM i'd recommend creating a .rvmrc file for the project..

`echo 'rvm use 1.9.3@your-project-gemset --create' > ./.rvmrc`

Then when you `cd` into the project directory RVM will automatically pick up the right ruby :)

However if you would like to change your system's default ruby to 1.9.3 you can do this too:

`rvm use 1.9.3 --default`